# Error checking in .NET with SQL 2005

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, exception

Can I throw an exception on the SQL 2005 server so that I can catch it in C# code with SqlCommand.ExecuteQuery()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`RAISERROR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Errors raised with severity 1..10 will be informational messages that will trigger the [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event. Errors raised with severity 16 will be translated into [SqlError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx) objects attached to a [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx), which will be thrown by SqlClient  when you execute any of the SqlCommand methods ([ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx), [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), [ExecuteXmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader.aspx) and their async completion counterparts).

Do not use other severity for RAISERROR other than 1..10 and 16.

Answer (score 3):

Errors that occur on the SQL server bubble up to your .NET code as exceptions. To test, execute a query that will return an error (like a syntax error or something stupid) and watch for the exception in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this all the time. For example,

```
SELECT @SurveyCode = (SELECT Value FROM Setting WHERE [Key] = @PubCode)

IF @SurveyCode IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('No survey code for the specified PubCode (%s ) in Setting table.', 16, 1, @PubCode)
    RETURN
END
```

---

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
  Class=16
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  LineNumber=15
  Message="No survey code for the specified PubCode ((null) ) in Setting table."
  Number=50000
  Procedure="GetSetting"
  Server="(local)"
  Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       ....
```